# array of images in static folder with vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

From my python API I get 4 image classes, I need to return those with an image. the images are stored in the static vuejs folder.

problem: the return is "00001100" the images are named "00001100-engine.jpg". the extra value "-engine.jpg" is variable.

How do I get an array/object/JSON off all the images in this folder?